# How do I install wine x86 components on Ubuntu 12.04 x64?

Tags: 64-bit, wine

I'm trying to [install Microsoft Office 2010](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/how-to-install-microsoft-office-suite-2010-in-ubuntu-12-04-using-wine-1-5/) on my Ubuntu 12.04 x64 installation, however, I can't install dotnet20 or msxml6 because of x64 and/or preprocessor errors.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PlayOnLinux
[image: Install via the software center]
to install the software for you pretty much automatically.

*There is a way to get the 32bit components otherwise, but I have not concretely determined if my hunch is correct (what happened in my case is that I installed a 32bit application and the 32bit subdirectory in the Wine drive was created automatically).*

Comment: I just installed it, and although it works for things like IE6-8, it errs on my x86-x64 Office disc, saying it doesn't support the architecture.

Comment: @rebelliard you can report a bug. It could support in in theory, but they will need to update their script.